# Eclipse console with ansi input

Tags: java, eclipse, console, osgi

I am using jline and the Apache karaf console a lot. When I start karaf from a linux terminal I have all the features like history, inline editing, completion. These work by using the tab and cursor keys.
I think these are ansi key sequences but I am not sure.

The big problem in eclipse is that in the eclipse console all these special keys do not seem to get forwarded to my application. For example the up cursor key does not show the last command from the history but moves the cursor in the console window up one character.

So all the nice features of jline and the karaf shell are lost if I start my process using the IDE. Is there a way to get that working in eclipse?

If it needs to be coded what eclipse project provides the console?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Eclipse [help](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fconsole_shell.htm) for the OSGi console shell you only get command history and tab completion by connecting to the console shell using telnet or ssh.

For telnet you can start eclipse specifying `-console <port>` and then using telnet to connect to the port.

The console is implemented using a number of plugins, the main ones being

```
org.apache.felix.gogo.command
org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime
org.apache.felix.gogo.shell
org.eclipse.equinox.console
```

Comment: In my case I am using the karaf shell which is a bit different but I am confedent that this could also work there.

Comment: Hmmm .. I am not sure if this is what I am looking for. I know that you can start telnet in the gogo shell or ssh in the karaf shell. What I am looking for is to get those features in the eclipse console window without opening a separate terminal window and doing the remote connect by hand.

Comment: You can't, the basic Eclipse console does not support these.

Comment: Yes .. that is also what I found. Any idea where to bug the eclipse people to implement this or help with it? In the vast space of the eclipse projects I do not even know which project provides the console.

Comment: You can add a bug asking for an enhancement on Eclipse [bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org)